# Solve a set of nonlinear equations for a discrete value in SymPy

Tags: math, sympy, physics, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations for a discrete value in SymPy. The system constists of 7 equations.

Here's my code:

```
import math
from CoolProp.CoolProp import PropsSI
import sympy as sym

alpha_Fluid, Re_l, v_Fluid, mdot_Fluid, Nu_Fluid, Nu_l_lam, Nu_l_turb = sym.symbols('alpha_Fluid, Re_l, v_Fluid, mdot_Fluid, Nu_Fluid, Nu_l_lam, Nu_l_turb')

################################ Discrete Parameters ################################
fluid = 'Nitrogen';
p_Fluid = 1.1e5; 
T_Fluid = 80; 
T_ZP = 300; 
Pr_Fluid = PropsSI("PRANDTL",'P|gas', p_Fluid, 'T', (T_Fluid+T_ZP)/2, fluid);
eta_Fluid = PropsSI("VISCOSITY",'P|gas', p_Fluid, 'T', (T_Fluid+T_ZP)/2, fluid);
lambda_Fluid = PropsSI("CONDUCTIVITY",'P|gas', p_Fluid, 'T', (T_Fluid+T_ZP)/2, fluid);
rho_Fluid = PropsSI("DMASS",'P|gas', p_Fluid, 'T', (T_Fluid+T_ZP)/2, fluid);
Bi = 0.1;
r_ZP = 7e-3; 
lambda_ZP = 230; 
L_ZP_Biot = r_ZP; 
L_ZP_KONV = (math.pi/2)*2*r_ZP; 
A_Inflow = 4e-3; 
A_Anstr = 2*math.pi*r_ZP*A_Inflow; 


Eq1 = sym.Eq((alpha_Fluid*L_ZP_Biot)/lambda_ZP, Bi)
Eq2 = sym.Eq((alpha_Fluid*L_ZP_KONV)/lambda_Fluid, Nu_Fluid) 
Eq3 = sym.Eq(0.664*(Re_l)**(1/2)*Pr_Fluid**(1/3),Nu_l_lam)
Eq4 = sym.Eq((0.037*Re_l**(0.8)*Pr_Fluid)/(1+2.443*Re_l**(-0.1)*(Pr_Fluid**(2/3)-1)), Nu_l_turb)
Eq5 = sym.Eq(0.3 + (Nu_l_lam**2 + Nu_l_turb**2)**(1/2), Nu_Fluid)
Eq6 = sym.Eq((rho_Fluid*v_Fluid*L_ZP_KONV)/eta_Fluid, Re_l)
Eq7 = sym.Eq((mdot_Fluid*rho_Fluid)/A_Anstr, v_Fluid)

result = sym.solve([Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4, Eq5, Eq6, Eq7],mdot_Fluid)
print(result)
```

I expect a discrete value for the variable 'mdot_Fluid'.

But the solution I obtain is the following: {mdot_Fluid: 8.99341199537194e-5*v_Fluid}.

My first guess is, that the whole system is underdetermined, which is weird, because I have 7 equations and 7 unknows.

Comment: If you have a system of 7 ***linear*** equations and 7 unknowns, and the equations are ***linearly independent***, then there will be exactly one solution. If the equations are not linearly independent, or if the equations are not linear, you cannot expect to get a unique solution just because the number of equations and the number of variables are equal.

Comment: I see several `**(1/2)` and `**(1/3)` in your equations, so I would guess these are not linear equations.

Comment: Also note that you asked sympy to solve for `mdot_fluid`, so sympy thinks that this is a system of equations with only one unknown, `mdot_fluid`, and the other variables are treated as constants, not unknowns.

Comment: I don't recommend mixing math.pi with sympy; use sympy.pi instead

Comment: And if you're only interested in numerical solutions and not in symbolic solutions then sympy is not the right tool! Use scipy instead.

Comment: BTW, when asking a question on stackoverflow, it is very strongly recommended to make a [mre]. In particular, could you try to reproduce the issue without the dependence on CoolProp.CoolProp.PropsSI? The people here who are susceptible to read your question and help you most likely aren't familar with PropSI and won't be bothered with installing that library, and it doesn't seem to be directly linked to your issue, and we don't know what type of object is returned by PropsSI, so this is just confusing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You are right, I should've defined the other variables as unknows. I also used `scipy` in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of your responses I solved the problem with the `scipy.fsolve` method. I made the mistake to solve for only the variable 'mdot_Fluid', while I should have solved for the other unknown variables too. Here's my solution:

```py
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

##### Constants ######
p_Fluid = 1.1e5; # 
T_Fluid = 80; 
T_ZP = 300; 
Pr_Fluid = 0.74;
eta_Fluid = 1.23e-5;
lambda_Fluid = 0.0174;
rho_Fluid = 1.96;
r_ZP = 7e-3; 
lambda_ZP = 230; 
L_ZP_Biot = r_ZP; 
L_ZP_KONV = (math.pi/2)*2*r_ZP; 
A_Inflow = 4e-3; 
A_Anstr = (2*math.pi*r_ZP*A_Inflow)/2; 
Bi = 0.01; 

def calc_massflux(g):
    alpha_Fluid, Re_l, v_Fluid, mdot_Fluid, Nu_Fluid, Nu_l_lam, Nu_l_turb = g;
    return [(alpha_Fluid*L_ZP_Biot)/lambda_ZP - Bi, 
            (alpha_Fluid*L_ZP_KONV)/lambda_Fluid - Nu_Fluid, 
            0.664*(Re_l)**(1/2)*Pr_Fluid**(1/3) - Nu_l_lam, 
            (0.037*Re_l**(0.8)*Pr_Fluid)/(1+2.443*Re_l**(-0.1)*(Pr_Fluid**(2/3)-1)) - Nu_l_turb,
            0.3 + (Nu_l_lam**2 + Nu_l_turb**2)**(1/2) - Nu_Fluid,
            (rho_Fluid*v_Fluid*L_ZP_KONV)/eta_Fluid - Re_l,
            mdot_Fluid/(rho_Fluid*A_Anstr) - v_Fluid]
            
alpha_Fluid, Re_l, v_Fluid, mdot_Fluid, Nu_Fluid, Nu_l_lam, Nu_l_turb = fsolve(calc_massflux, (1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
print(mdot_Fluid)
```

Comment: This solution differs from the one shown above. Whatever you do, check your solution in the original equations (written as expressions like `Eq1.lhs-Eq1.rhs`) to see that you are happy with the solution you obtained.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved as 6 linear equations and a 7th nonlinear. Solve all but equation 4 and then substitute the solution into equation 4 and use `nsolve` with an initial guess for `v_Fluid` to get an answer.

```py
import math
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *
math=sym  # don't use math.pi use sympy.pi
alpha_Fluid, Re_l, v_Fluid, mdot_Fluid, Nu_Fluid, Nu_l_lam, Nu_l_turb = sym.symbols('alpha_Fluid, Re_l, v_Fluid, mdot_Fluid, Nu_Fluid, Nu_l_lam, Nu_l_turb')

################################ Discrete Parameters ################################
fluid = 'Nitrogen';
p_Fluid = 1.1e5; 
T_Fluid = 80; 
T_ZP = 300; 
Pr_Fluid = 0.74;
eta_Fluid = 1.23e-5;
lambda_Fluid = 0.0174;
rho_Fluid = 1.96;
Bi = 0.1;
r_ZP = 7e-3; 
lambda_ZP = 230; 
L_ZP_Biot = r_ZP; 
L_ZP_KONV = (math.pi/2)*2*r_ZP; 
A_Inflow = 4e-3; 
A_Anstr = 2*math.pi*r_ZP*A_Inflow; 


Eq1 = sym.Eq((alpha_Fluid*L_ZP_Biot)/lambda_ZP, Bi)
Eq2 = sym.Eq((alpha_Fluid*L_ZP_KONV)/lambda_Fluid, Nu_Fluid) 
Eq3 = sym.Eq(0.664*(Re_l)**(1/2)*Pr_Fluid**(1/3),Nu_l_lam)
Eq4 = sym.Eq((0.037*Re_l**(0.8)*Pr_Fluid)/(1+2.443*Re_l**(-0.1)*(Pr_Fluid**(2/3)-1)), Nu_l_turb)
Eq5 = sym.Eq(0.3 + (Nu_l_lam**2 + Nu_l_turb**2)**(1/2), Nu_Fluid)
Eq6 = sym.Eq((rho_Fluid*v_Fluid*L_ZP_KONV)/eta_Fluid, Re_l)
Eq7 = sym.Eq((mdot_Fluid*rho_Fluid)/A_Anstr, v_Fluid)
req = nsimplify(Tuple(*[Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq5, Eq6, Eq7]))
result = sym.solve(req, dict=True)[0]
nl = Eq4.subs(result)
nsolve(nl.subs(reps), 1)
```

Alternatively, square both sides of `nl`, replace `v_Fluid**.1` with a positive `x` and use `real_roots` on the result

```py
>>> eq=nsimplify(nl.lhs**2-nl.rhs**2).as_numer_denom()[0].subs(root(v_Fluid,10),var('x',positive=True)).n()
>>> [(i**10).n() for i in real_roots(eq)] # x^(1/10) = i so x = i**10
[920.247842938558, 8.55655777550056e-8, 8.55656098540597e-8, 721.920699464287]
```

You will have to substitute these values into `nl.lhs-nl.rhs` and `result` to see which ones (if any) are actually solutions. The scaling of the equations is not what one would desire, however, with these numerical values. I would proceed with caution.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I should have made it clear that the 4 variables `Pr_Fluid, eta_Fluid, lambda_Fluid, rho_Fluid` are known.